# Change Window upon flashdrive detection Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, usb

So far I have a GUI but right now I'm having a problem on how to change the window upon usb insertion. I tried pyudev for monitoring devices but whenever I add it in my GUI code, it doesn't run even though these codes worked when separated. Also I want to list the files in the GUI so that the user can select which file to print. Thank you in Advance! :)
This is my code for detection of usb devices.

```
import pyudev

context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')

for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
    if device.action == 'add':
        print('{} connected'.format(device))

    if device.action == 'remove':
        print('{} removed' .format(device))
```